# Question about a proof involving polar decomposition of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, trace

Consider the following theorem in Murphy's book "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory":

[image: rp]

Can someone explain why the marked equality is correct? I know $|u^*|^2 = uu^* = w |u|^2 w^*$ but can't see why this equals $(w|u|w^*)^2$.

Context:

$\Vert \cdot \Vert _1$ is the trace class norm.

Comment: Because $w^*w=1$.

Comment: @Chrystomath. Why is that? $w$ is a partial isometry. Do these operators have this property?

Comment: Isometries need not satisfy $ww^*=1$ but they do satisfy $w^*w=1$, at least on the image of $|u|$.

Comment: Note that $|A|=\sqrt{A^*A}$ so $|u^*|^2= (u^*)^*u^* = uu^*$ which is equal to $w|u|^2w^*=(w|u|w^*)^2$ by what came before. Now $w|u|w^*$ is positive and positive roots of positive things are unique, so $|u^*|=w|u|w^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Murphy's book theorem 2.3.3 it is proven (see the implication $(4) \implies (2)$) that if $w$ is a partial isometry, then $w^*w$ is the projection on $\ker(w)^\perp =  \ker (u)^\perp  = \ker (|u|)^\perp = \overline{\operatorname{im}(|u|^*)}= \overline{\operatorname{im}(|u|)}$. Hence, $w^*w$ is the identity on the image of $|u|$ and consequently
$$(w|u|w^*)^2 = w|u|w^*w|u|w^* = w|u|^2w^*$$

Answer (score -1):

$(w\vert u \vert w^*)^2 = (w \vert u \vert w^*)(w \vert u \vert w^*) = w \vert u \vert (w^*w) \vert u \vert w^* = \ldots$

Comment: Yes, I also got this far... Please fill in the other steps!

Comment: @user745578 So your question was why is $w^* w$ equal to the identity? That wasn't clear to me, sorry. It seems it was all answered above. Don't know if a downvote was necessary, but oh well.